# an error occurred forwarding 9090 -> 9090: error forwarding port 9090

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, k3s

I installed Prometheus in my K3S cluster, the image from [here](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-worawutchan/kube-prometheus-stack), the image is included Prometheus and Grafana, the problem comes when I forward the port.

```
#kubectl port-forward -n prometheus prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-0 9090
```

this is the error

```
orwarding from 127.0.0.1:9090 -> 9090

Forwarding from [::1]:9090 -> 9090

Handling connection for 9090

E1220 15:17:44.164690  373403 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 9090 -> 9090: error forwarding port 9090 to pod 044703990a9e4d5562dd26ca78084993038401acf3647ede3323991c512923c1, uid : failed to execute portforward in network namespace "/var/run/netns/cni-7bc4f557-7fa0-d886-3e10-47f587c4633b": failed to dial 9090: dial tcp4: lookup localhost: Try again

Handling connection for 9090

E1220 15:17:54.162609  373403 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 9090 -> 9090: error forwarding port 9090 to pod 044703990a9e4d5562dd26ca78084993038401acf3647ede3323991c512923c1, uid : failed to execute portforward in network namespace "/var/run/netns/cni-7bc4f557-7fa0-d886-3e10-47f587c4633b": failed to dial 9090: dial tcp4: lookup localhost: Try again

Handling connection for 9090

E1220 15:24:49.689777  373403 portforward.go:340] error creating error stream for port 9090 -> 9090: Timeout occurred

Handling connection for 9090

E1220 15:24:59.710498  373403 portforward.go:362] error creating forwarding stream for port 9090 -> 9090: Timeout occurred

Handling connection for 9090

E1220 15:25:09.742766  373403 portforward.go:362] error creating forwarding stream for port 9090 -> 9090: Timeout occurred

Handling connection for 9090
```

I do the same thing to Grafana using port 3000, but it is totally fine.

```
#kubectl port-forward -n prometheus prometheus-grafana-8664fc46fd-j3hns 3000
```

this is pod description for prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-0

```
Name:         prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-0

Namespace:    prometheus

Priority:     0

Node:         k3s-agent1/192.168.20.20
Start Time:   Mon, 20 Dec 2021 11:20:15 +0800

Labels:       app=prometheus

              controller-revision-hash=prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-5647b8f994

              operator.prometheus.io/name=prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus

              operator.prometheus.io/shard=0

              prometheus=prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus

              statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-0

Annotations:  <none>

Status:       Running

IP:           10.42.1.84

IPs:

  IP:           10.42.1.84

Controlled By:  StatefulSet/prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus

Containers:

  prometheus:

    Container ID:  containerd://3165a8c3d2cac548f91235330be1b2880db19f68d409205a8469da39ad0a50c9

    Image:         quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.22.1

    Image ID:      quay.io/prometheus/prometheus@sha256:b899dbd1b9017b9a379f76ce5b40eead01a62762c4f2057eacef945c3c22d210

    Port:          9090/TCP

    Host Port:     0/TCP

    Args:

      --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles

      --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries

      --config.file=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml

      --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus

      --storage.tsdb.retention.time=10d

      --web.enable-lifecycle

      --storage.tsdb.no-lockfile

      --web.external-url=http://prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus.prometheus:9090

      --web.route-prefix=/

    State:          Running

      Started:      Mon, 20 Dec 2021 11:20:17 +0800

    Ready:          True

    Restart Count:  0

    Readiness:      http-get http://:web/-/ready delay=0s timeout=3s period=5s #success=1 #failure=120

    Environment:    <none>

    Mounts:

      /etc/prometheus/certs from tls-assets (ro)

      /etc/prometheus/config_out from config-out (ro)

      /etc/prometheus/rules/prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0 from prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0 (rw)

      /prometheus from prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-db (rw)

      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-slt5r (ro)

  config-reloader:

    Container ID:  containerd://c526856553816a463bb7d9562277b61d201a6bed6562f2ae97f0dd1a7794c72b

    Image:         quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader:v0.44.0

    Image ID:      quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader@sha256:6659cb3d97b5f846b5e1651ca1ab95189509f899713c727143f1bc50cc6e57cf

    Port:          8080/TCP

    Host Port:     0/TCP

    Command:

      /bin/prometheus-config-reloader

    Args:

      --listen-address=:8080

      --reload-url=http://127.0.0.1:9090/-/reload

      --config-file=/etc/prometheus/config/prometheus.yaml.gz

      --config-envsubst-file=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml

      --watched-dir=/etc/prometheus/rules/prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0

    State:          Running

      Started:      Mon, 20 Dec 2021 11:20:20 +0800

    Ready:          True

    Restart Count:  0

    Limits:

      cpu:     100m

      memory:  25Mi

    Requests:

      cpu:     100m

      memory:  25Mi

    Environment:

      POD_NAME:  prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-0 (v1:metadata.name)

      SHARD:     0

    Mounts:

      /etc/prometheus/config from config (rw)

      /etc/prometheus/config_out from config-out (rw)

      /etc/prometheus/rules/prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0 from prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0 (rw)

      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-slt5r (ro)

Conditions:

  Type              Status

  Initialized       True 

  Ready             True 

  ContainersReady   True 

  PodScheduled      True 

Volumes:

  config:

    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)

    SecretName:  prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus

    Optional:    false

  tls-assets:

    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)

    SecretName:  prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-tls-assets

    Optional:    false

  config-out:

    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)

    Medium:     

    SizeLimit:  <unset>

  prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0:

    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)

    Name:      prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0

    Optional:  false

  prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-db:

    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)

    Medium:     

    SizeLimit:  <unset>

  kube-api-access-slt5r:

    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)

    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607

    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt

    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>

    DownwardAPI:             true

QoS Class:                   Burstable

Node-Selectors:              <none>

Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s

                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s

Events:                      <none>
```

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: I use K3S, Kubernetes Distribution
k3s version v1.21.7+k3s1

Comment: I replicated your setup and it's working good (I also installed Prometheus chart in the `prometheus` namespace). Could please tell me on which OS your k3s cluster is setup? Do you have any worker nodes? Are you sure that nothing else is not listening on the 9090 port? Do you have any firewall enabled maybe? Any additional, custom network settings?

Comment: yes, I do have, I disable all the ufw and iptables for all my worker node and master and my Prometheus prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-0 connected to the master. yes I don't see my 9090 is running on my system, do I have to open/allow the port through ufw?

Comment: If you have disabled the ufw and ipatables firewalls, there no need open/allow the port. I tried again with worker node configured and it is working good, could you maybe check if port is opened and which process is listening (before and when `kubectl port-forward` command is running), for example I have something like this: `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9090          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      38034/kubectl`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but using EKS. The difference is that also port-forward Grafana shows the same error.

Comment: I Have no idea, but I just re-installed the things, and now I am using Grafana and Prometheus from Bitnami.